# Syntactic proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to prove (false => p) syntactically, every attempt so far has been in vain despite using the deduction theorem or (p=>p). Any hints first would be welcomed.

Comment: It depends on the proof system used. In [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4), there is the rule ($\bot$E): $\bot \vdash \varphi$.

Comment: Which system are you using? Which axioms or infrence rules do you have?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i have the following axioms: p=>(q=>p) , [p=>(q=>r)] => [(p=>q)=>(p=>r)] and [(p=>false)=>false)]=>p and my deduction rule is modus ponens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, I'll use $\bot$ in place of $\text f$ (i.e. *false*).

Ax.1)  $p \to (q \to p)$

Ax.2) $[p \to (q \to r)] \to [(p \to q) \to (p \to r)]$

Ax.3) $((p \to \bot) \to \bot) \to p$

*Proof*

1) $[((p \to \bot) \to \bot) \to p] \to [\bot \to (((p \to \bot) \to \bot) \to p)]$ --- from Ax.1 with $\bot$ in place of $q$ and $(((p \to \bot) \to \bot) \to p)$ in place of $p$

2) $\bot \to (((p \to \bot) \to \bot) \to p)$ --- from 1) and Ax.3 by *Modus Ponens*

3) $[\bot \to (((p \to \bot) \to \bot) \to p)] \to [(\bot \to ((p \to \bot) \to \bot)) \to (\bot \to p)]$ --- from Ax.2

4) $(\bot \to ((p \to \bot) \to \bot)) \to (\bot \to p)$ --- from 2) and 3) by *MP*

5) $\bot \to ((p \to \bot) \to \bot)$ --- from Ax.1 with $\bot$ in place of $p$ and $(p \to \bot)$ in place of $q$

> 6) $\bot \to p$ --- from 4) and 5) by *MP*

Comment: i was soo close, thanks :)

Comment: Is there any sort of technique for writing syntactic proofs or does it only come from intuition and practice?